# "Connection Reset" occurs on ANY http requests if it is a PUT or DELETE request

Tags: networking, ubuntu

My server recently reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 and is experiencing very strange issues: It is connection resetting all requests that is a `PUT` or `DELETE` request. Here are some examples:

(It's just an empty nginx server, by the way)

```bsh
curl <ip>
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
```

```bsh
curl -X POST <ip>
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
...
```

And now the fun part: It connection resets `PUT` and `DELETE`.

```bsh
curl -X PUT <ip>
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
curl -X DELETE <ip>
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Another place that makes this weird is, when posting a random, non-RESTful request, the connection is just fine:

```bsh
curl -X BLARRGHRGH <ip>
<html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
```

I looked into this by using `telnet`, only finding that connection unexpectedly closes once the request is a `PUT` and `DELETE` request:

```bsh
telnet <ip> 80
Trying <ip>...
Connected to <ip>.
Escape character is '^]'.
PUT / HTTP/1.1

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

GET or POST on the other hand, works fine. And this problem persists on all ports and all softwares, such as a jupyter lab. It's running on the port 8080, and it's also the reason I started to look into this problem:

[GET works as the web page is shown flawlessly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IZJf.png)

However it cannot save or delete files, or modify them:

[Failed to fetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wnqL.png)

- System version: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
- Routing table: [Routing table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih8q1.png)
- And finally, `iptables -S`: [iptables -S](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWr5n.jpg)

If anyone had any idea, please tell me. I am getting a little bit desperate to resolve this issue. Thanks!!

**EDIT:** as @grawity pointed out, I ran `tcpdump` and saw this:

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eno1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
02:40:41.372611 IP 10.61.144.243.64630 > 172.31.152.6.80: Flags [S], seq 1059357560, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 130796586 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
E..@..@.=.^b
=.......v.P?$.x.........L.............
...*........
02:40:41.372676 IP 172.31.152.6.80 > 10.61.144.243.64630: Flags [S.], seq 1764151353, ack 1059357561, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2322551000 ecr 130796586,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E..<..@.@.[f....
=...P.vi&.9?$.y..q ...........
.oP....*....
02:40:41.374916 IP 10.61.144.243.64630 > 172.31.152.6.80: Flags [.], ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 130796588 ecr 2322551000], length 0
E..4..@.=.^n
=.......v.P?$.yi&.:...
.W.....
...,.oP.
02:40:41.422352 IP 10.61.144.243.64630 > 172.31.152.6.80: Flags [R.], seq 1, ack 1, win 8224, options [nop,nop,TS val 130796634 ecr 2322551000], length 0
E..4fU@.=...
=.......v.P?$.yi&.:..  .......
...Z.oP.
```

This is a curl request. There is no PUT or eligible text here whatsoever. Which is weird because if this request is manufactured by `telnet`, the first line could be caught, and it makes sense because `telnet` always flushes after a complete line:

```
02:43:14.735256 IP 10.61.144.243.65219 > 172.31.152.6.80: Flags [P.], seq 1:17, ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 130949575 ecr 2322695469], length 16: HTTP: PUT / HTTP/1.1
E..D..@.=.^^
=.........P...........
z......
..!..q.-PUT / HTTP/1.1

02:43:14.735310 IP 172.31.152.6.80 > 10.61.144.243.65219: Flags [.], ack 17, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 2322704367 ecr 130949575], length 0
E..4..@.@.W.....
=...P...............|.....
.q....!.
02:43:23.386996 IP 10.61.144.243.65219 > 172.31.152.6.80: Flags [R.], seq 17, ack 1, win 8224, options [nop,nop,TS val 130958209 ecr 2322704367], length 0
E..4fU@.=...
=.........P..........  .......
..C..q..
```

However after the second enter, the connection was closed unexpectedly. I was starting to think maybe this is due to a packet inspection I dont know in my school? Does that make sense?

**EDIT:** `curl -v`:

```bsh
curl -v -X PUT 172.31.152.6
*   Trying 172.31.152.6...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 172.31.152.6 (172.31.152.6) port 80 (#0)
> PUT / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 172.31.152.6
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Fire up `tcpdump -An "port 80"` **on the server**. Does the server receive the PUT request? Does it look like the server sends the TCP RST packet, or does it look like the server _receives_ one from the client?

Comment: In your telnet example, you claimed HTTP/1.1, but you didn't include HTTP 1.1's mandatory `Host:` header. Does it behave differently if you include a valid Host header?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you're trying illegal/malformed PUTs and DELETEs and instead of getting back an HTTP error code, you're getting a connection reset. So your complaint is than nginx is not handling malformed PUTs and DELETEs correctly? Does it handle well-formed PUTs and DELETEs correctly? Like it you use curl's `-T file` option to PUT-upload a file (and provide a real URI with a writable target path on the server instead of just a bare IP address for the server), does it work better?

Comment: @Spiff , not just malformed PUTs & DELETEs, but legal PUTs and DELETEs. This is preventing me to use jupyter, seafile, etc because the inability to use those requests. The whole system's networking has this weird problem. Javascript `fetch` or `$.ajax` should be valid, and I am still getting connection reset from them.

Comment: @grawity After tcpdump I found something interesting: curl requests are not even shown on `tcpdump`, just an empty TCP header. `telnet` however, gets the `PUT / HTTP/1.1` line and after I hit enter the second time, the connection was immediately  reset. Please check my modified question for outputs and stuffs.

Comment: What does `curl -v` show?

Comment: @NickT , please check out my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logs show that:

1. The packet with the request does not even arrive at the server. Tcpdump would show anything that was received on the network interface, regardless of server-side configuration.
2. The client thinks it's receiving a TCP RST from the server, but tcpdump on the server doesn't actually show it being sent. Instead it shows a TCP RST *arriving from* the client's address.

The only conclusion is that there is a firewall running some kind of "intrusion prevention system" in between your client and your server – it is blocking the packets it thinks are malicious for some reason, and it is sending *spoofed* TCP RSTs to both peers "on behalf of" the opposite peer.

---

Use HTTPS to work around the issue – it will make the exact request contents invisible to all middleboxes and other intermediate devices.

To narrow down where the blocking is happening, try sending the same blocked requests from the same LAN to other unrelated servers (over plain HTTP), and from other clients (e.g. from a 4G connection) to your own server.

Comment: As it turns out, all IPs within this intranet will receive a connection reset whenever it is a PUT/DELETE request. Thanks!